# flutter iOS Simulator - Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I'm getting this error when I try to run my application on the iOS simulator:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         9,2s
Xcode build done.                                           27,9s
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
```

At the end of the `Xcode build done. 27,9s` print in the terminal, the App opens in the iOS simulator for a few milliseconds, but is instantly closed, and a crash screen from Xcode is opened.

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.8.0-9.0.pre.18, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64, locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.8.0-9.0.pre.18 on channel master at /Users/rafael/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f945ad99c3 (55 minutes ago), 2023-02-10 00:05:44 +0100
    • Engine revision 40e17fb524
    • Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-218.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.21.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/rafael/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0-rc2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • 49BFE69F-8CDD-4726-A6A4-60AC1E87E6E9 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing a package that I had in the application that has the pub `google_mobile_ads` in its `.yaml`, and as I am not implementing Ads in this App I did not configure the necessary items in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Info.plist`.